# windows phone 8 - Sqlite exception with some persian character

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, persian

in my windows phone 8 application i want to update the value a field in a table of database. 
when updated value contains some Persian character it throws an exception `unrecognized token :`
i found the problem occurs with the following character : `ا`

why this exception occurs. does it relate to utf-16 encoding of string object in c#?

[image]

Comment: ok i didn't find any solution for this problem . instead of updating record first i delete the record and then insert it.